# Code won't stop running

Tags: vba

I've applied the following code to a table that needs all but the first row deleted for new data to be pasted into it.

```
Sub KeepFormulas()

Dim sRow, lCol As Integer

    sRow = ActiveCell.Row

    lCol = Cells(sRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column

    For Each cell In Range(Cells(sRow, 1), Cells(sRow, lCol))

    If cell.HasFormula = False Then cell.ClearContents

        Next cell

End Sub
```

After the last cell in the range is cleared of its content, the active cell becomes the first cell in the first row and the code continues to infinity between the last two lines of code. How do I stop the code from running once all cells in the range have been cleared (unless it contains a formula).

Comment: I think you have your hands mixed up `xlToRight` should be `xlToLeft`

Comment: OMG, you're amazing; that worked! I've been staring at this for far too long. Thank you!